# union self with temporary table

Tags: mysql, union

The union with same temporary table is not working but same query works if it is a permanent table. My full query is as following. If t_pair is a permanent table, it would work.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t_pair AS
select distinct pr_ns_a, pr_ew_a, pr_ns_b, pr_ew_b from t_score;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t_partner AS
select distinct pr_ns_a as partner from t_pair
union
select distinct pr_ew_a as partner from t_pair
union
select distinct pr_ns_b as partner from t_pair
union
select distinct pr_ew_b as partner from t_pair
order by partner;
```

Answer (score 1):

you can't refer to the temporary table more than once in the same query

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/temporary-table-problems.html